# ThinkPad Carbon X1 gen9 stuck on black screen when shut down

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, shutdown, thinkpad

For the last 5 shut downs, my laptop has been going to black screen as if shut down (no keyboard light or anything), but the fans continue to run. Pushing on the power off button does not do anything and I am basically forced to wait for the laptop to run out of battery. There does not seem to be any specific error message popping.

I have a ThinkPad Carbon X1 gen 9 with Ubuntu 20.04 (dual boot with Windows, but I never use the latter).

Any help is more than welcome as it is a quite annoying issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This actually happens to me I just received the Carbon X1 Gen 9 with ubuntu and it does the same thing.  I have to hold the power button down for 10 seconds to force it to shut off.  Seeking a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I've no answer yet but I've the same issue and raised the problem elsewhere:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1965219
- https://github.com/fwupd/firmware-lenovo/issues/210

You'll find discussion with references and failed attempts there.

I've encountered the problem in two distinct forms:

1. A black screen with no keyboard, mouse, or network, although journalctl shows some internal activity continues.
2. The gnome-shell ignore the keyboard dies but weyland/Xorg still moves the mouse pointer, over either a black screen or clock screen. Also   Fn+Ctrl+Alt+F5 or ssh still works, but only killing gnome-shell saves the system.

I suspect the Lenovo/Ubuntu OEM kernel causes this problem, so it should either be downgraded or replaced with a mainline kernel, or maybe minimize this proprietary mess by replacing Ubuntu with Debian.

Anecdotally there exists a correlation between usage and this intermittent crash, but seemingly allocated memory exceeding swap does not trigger the crash, although maybe mmapped pages make computing this hard, so who knows.

I'll likely first explore mainline kernels, but then if issues persist just replace Ubuntu with Debian, which always gave me minimal trouble in the past.  I do not know enough about Ubuntu OEM kernels to downgrade them.

As a work around, I suggest turning off automatic suspend in settings -> power, and then using the laptop only as a desktop.

---

It's less bad if you disable suspend when plugged in.  I also notice Mailspring running worsens problems.

There is some kernel bug causing all this, so upgrading to Linux 5.17 likely fixes things.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issues.  Have not updated to latest bios flash, but have tried many things.

I am motivated to get Ubuntu 18.04 to work because of the requirements of it by the Nvidia Jetson development kit dependency on it.  Ubuntu 20.04 does not work on Nvidia dev kit for my Jetson Nano model.

But if you don’t have a hard dependency like that it is best here is to update to Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04 as they both work on this laptop just fine.

Ubuntu 18.04 is out of support and that means no patches for anything as of April 2023!  Taking a risk running on this!

I am thinking about trying Debian instead since there is the Nvidia Jetson Nano dependency for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).